# Suppress UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer warnings from external libraries

Tags: c++, suppress-warnings, ubsan

I have an UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer build (`-fsanitize=undefined`), and I am trying to suppress a warning for UB in an external library that is out of my control.  The clang/gcc docs mention [`__attribute__((no_sanitize("undefined")))`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#no-sanitize), but to my surprise it seems that this attribute does not suppress warnings from subroutines.

[Simple example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/eenMc16Eq):

```
//__attribute__((no_sanitize("shift"))) // this correctly suppresses the warning
int bar() {
    return 1 << 64;
}

__attribute__((no_sanitize("shift"))) // this does not
int foo() {
    return bar();
}

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Since this attribute doesn't seem to work, how can I suppress this warning?  I could remove the entire target from my UBSan build, but that seems incredibly heavy-handed.

Comment: For extra context, [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/66EhPGsv5) is an example of the specific bug I am trying to suppress.  And [here](https://github.com/boostorg/ptr_container/issues/18) is the related bug report in boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang has pragmas to apply attributes in bulk:

```
#pragma clang attribute push (__attribute__((no_sanitize("undefined"))), apply_to=function)
// ...
#pragma clang attribute pop
```

Wrapping the header in those disables the check in your example:

```
#pragma clang attribute push (__attribute__((no_sanitize("undefined"))), apply_to=function)
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#pragma clang attribute pop

struct Foo{};

void bar()
{
    boost::ptr_vector<boost::nullable<Foo>> v;
    v.push_back(nullptr);
    v.push_back(new Foo);
}

int main()
{
    bar();
}
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: I’m getting an error `unused attribute 'no_sanitize' in '#pragma clang attribute push' region` when trying exactly that (using Apple’s Clang 13). Any ideas?

Comment: I also got stuck at `unused attribute`; the only workaround I've found was to compile with `-fsanitize-ignorelist=foo.txt` instead, using `src:` lines in `foo.txt` to match troublesome header files.